# border radius not applying for ionic modals in Android

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to apply the border-radius property for ionic modals. It is applying for chrome in desktop. But not applying for Android devices. How to achieve for Android?

```
.modal{
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

### view

```
<script id="AccountSearchModal.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <div class="modal">
        <header class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
            <h1 class="title">Account Search</h1>
            <div class="button button-clear" ng-click="modal.hide()">
                <span class="icon ion-close"></span>
            </div>
        </header>

        <content has-header="true" padding="true">
            <div class="list">
            <form name="accountCreateFrmTemp">
                <label class="item item-input margin-75" >                    
                    <input type="number" ng-model="accountNumber" placeholder="Account Number" name="accountNumber"/>
                </label> 

            </form>    
            </div>
        </content>       
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: i am using [ion-modal](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) and is working fine for me

Comment: thanks @varun..but i applied css  class for '.modal' and not working for me